# Scroll down a bit, wait, and repeat to bottom then wait a bit and reload page in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need a javascript that scrolls down a bit and wait and repeat this until it arrives at the end of the web page. then wait and reload the page. Here is my script so far

```html
<script>
        onbeforeunload = function () {
            window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
        onload = e=>{
            var d = document.documentElement;
            var offset = d.scrollTop + window.innerHeight;
            var height = d.offsetHeight;

            if (offset >= height) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    location.reload(1);
                }, 5000);

            }
          setInterval(function(){
              scrollBy(0,100);
          }, 5000);
        };
        onscroll = function() {
            var d = document.documentElement;
            var offset = d.scrollTop + window.innerHeight;
            var height = d.offsetHeight;

            if (offset >= height) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    location.reload(1);
                }, 5000);

            }
        };
    </script>
```

my problem is that my scrypt doesnt work really good. Sometimes it doesnt reload the page when it is at the end of the page.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your core logic is correct, just minor tweaks with respect to when you should call the recursive function. Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3fu5rL9n/4/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
function autoScrollandReload(scrollDistance,pause){
    /// start the interval with the pause in between executions
    var interval = setInterval(function(){

      /// denife values, not necessary but easyier to read
      var scrolled = window.pageYOffset;
      var scroll_size = document.body.scrollHeight;
      var scroll_remaining = scroll_size-scrolled;;

      /// check if scrolling is necessary
      if(scroll_remaining <= window.innerHeight){
         clearInterval(interval);

         /// scroll back to top
         window.scrollTo(0,0);

         /// do here what you want
         setTimeout(location.reload(),500);

      }else{
         window.scrollBy(0,scrollDistance);
      };                

    },pause);

};
```

Just call the function like this:

```
autoScrollandReload(100,5000);
```

This scrolls the page by 100px each 5 seconds

Comment: Thanks, but when it is at the end of the page it doesnt jjump to the start of the page. i fixed it here https://gist.github.com/Schnax/6ee73a01765c4708b06a4b5e47ee595f

Comment: fixed it also in my code, with a little less code. Your solution is also fine, but i like less code. each byte counts. Yes it would be possible to shrink a litte more, i gues around 50%. What do you think?

Comment: you are right. I would really like to see your shriked code